# In zsh, how to save interrupted (^C) commands to history automatically?

Tags: zsh

When a command is executed, the command is saved to history. Is there an option in zsh which automatically save the commands interrupted by `Ctrl-C` to history?

Comment: I am guessing by "interrupted" you you mean typing `^C` while still entering the command, because any running command should be saved to history, even if it is interrupted. If that is the case: would your main concern be to be able to put some command back, while just running something else first?

Comment: @Adaephon running something else first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mainly want to put a command back and run another first, I would suggest using the `push-line` widget, which is made just for that. It puts the current command on hold and clears the command line. After running another command, the original command is automatically restored. If you want to run multiple commands, you can repeat the process. As it works on a stack, you can even put multiple commands on hold. They will be restored in reverse order.

From the `zshzle(1)` manpage:

> **push-line (^Q ESC-Q ESC-q) (unbound) (unbound)**
>
> Push  the current buffer onto the buffer stack and clear the buffer.  Next time the editor starts up, the buffer will be popped off the top of the buffer stack and loaded into the editing buffer.

As you can see, by default it is bound in emacs mode (`bindkey -e`) to `^[q`, `^[Q` and `^Q`. That is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd>), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. The last of which only works if the option `FLOW_CONTROL` is disabled (`setopt noflowcontrol`).

---

There is also the `push-line-or-edit` widget. It behaves the same on a primary (`PS1`) prompt. But on a secondary (`PS2`) prompt it makes the whole multi-line construct (not just the current line) editable. Just like when you pull a multi-line construct from history.